# What is google action's active idle time until it exist the conversation?

Tags: actions-on-google

After invoking google action and doing some interaction when i leave it idle, action is exiting from the conversation. Is there a idle time limit for google action? Is it the default behaviour of google action or is it a problem? If there is a idle time limit what is the idle time for the action before it exits the conversation?

Answer (score 2):

While your Action is running, it will listen for input. If there is no input that seems to be valid after some time, you will receive three times a ["no input"](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/reprompts) intent which you can handle with an additional voice prompt to alert the user.

After three of these in a row, your Action will exit.

The amount of time between each no input is not specified. The microphone will listen for about five seconds for the user to speak, but this an estimate.